# Retrieve the element node from attribute node

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

For a node

```
<a:cs id='x'>
```

If current node is id (the attribute), how to retrieve Element node; i.e; a:cs?

Answer (score 0):

Simply with an XPath like `parent::tagname`. In your case that would accordingly be: `parent::a:cs`.

Be aware that this only works if `a` is properly declared as boinded taglib

Comment: No, XPath can have just "cs" in it but not the "a:cs", what I require.

Comment: SO you want to retrieve the parent of @id only if it is the `<a:cs>` tag?

Comment: What ever the parent name is in entirety. I mean with colons in this case. Since it's storing element information in "a:cs" form in the object internally. I just don't see any API to retrieve that.

Comment: With `parent::*` you will retrieve the parent of @id, whatever its name. If you want to get the name of this element, you can use `name(parent::*)`.

Comment: Actually it is perfectly possible to use an XPath such as `parent::a:cs`, but the prefix `a`has to be declared and bounded the appropriate namespace url.

Comment: In my case XPath is - /sld[1]/cSld[1]/spTree[1]/sp[1]/txBody[1]/p[1]/r[1]/rPr[1]/cs[1]. Notice cs rather than a:cs!